# Open All Links In New Tab EXCEPT TOC

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'd like to open all links within the main text of our articles in new tabs except for any hash links from our table of contents.

I'm sure it's pretty simple but I'm not sure how to specify to NOT include the TOC

Javascript used to open links in the main content of an article in a new tab:

`$(".single-post .entry-content p a").attr("target","_blank");`

Example article HTML

```
<h2>Jump Ahead!</h2>
<a href="#one">Header One</a>
<a href="#two">Header Two</a>


<h2><a name="one"></a>Header One</h2>

This is an example of a link that should open in a new tab <a href="https://example.com">New Tab</a>.

<h2><a name="two"></a>header Two</h2>
```

Any thoughts on how to NOT have #one and #two open a new tab but have example.com open in a new tab?

Comment: Is there a specific pattern between your TOC links? i.e. are they all in the same div, or all inside an `<h2>` tag like you're showing, etc...?

Comment: Not currently, I was hoping to somehow target the "#" that's in all of the TOC. I can wrap them all in the same div but I was hoping for a method where I didn't have to go back through a ton of articles.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

As you now mentioned, your TOC links all have an `href` that starts with a hash (#), so:

```js
$("a").each(function() {
  //if the link is not a TOC link
  if($(this).attr('href') && !$(this).attr('href').startsWith('#')) {
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Jump Ahead!</h2>
<a href="#one">Header One</a>
<a href="#two">Header Two</a>


<h2><a name="one"></a>Header One</h2>

This is an example of a link that should open in a new tab <a href="https://example.com" class="blank">New Tab</a>.

<h2><a name="two"></a>header Two</h2>
```

In this snippet, I'm looping over all `<a>` tags and checking if their href starts with a `#`. If it doesn't, I am adding the `target _blank` attribute.

---

Alternatively, if all TOC links are inside an `<h2>` tag, you can use the following selector to target all anchor tags that do not have an `<h2>` tag as parent:

```
$("a:not(h2 a)").attr("target", "_blank");
```

Comment: It would be a lot of work to go back through and change all links, I'm looking for ideally an automated approach. The TOC links aren't H2, unfortunately. Is there a way to exclude instances where the link has "#" in it?

Comment: I tried this `$(".single-post .entry-content p a").each(function() {
  if($(this).attr('href') && !$(this).attr('href').startsWith('#')) {
    $(this).attr('target', 'blank');
  }
});` But none of the external or other links open in new tab. Any ideas why? I want to specify just single posts and links in the main article. In other words, I don't want the menu to open in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

new tab or window (depends on your browsers settings)

include this parameter i you anchor tag (`<a href...>`)

`target="blank"`

so write like this

```
<h2>Jump Ahead!</h2>
<a href="#one">Header One</a>
<a href="#two">Header Two</a>


<h2><a name="one"></a>Header One</h2>

This is an example of a link that should open in a new tab <a href="https://example.com" target="blank">New Tab</a>.

<h2><a name="two"></a>header Two</h2>
```